# Linking input/output states and conditions in an input file

Tags: shell, awk

Consider the following CSV file:

```
A; B; ;
B; ; A;
C; ; E F;
D; ; E;
E; C; ;
```

The fields:

- `$1`: the `jname`. A unique id of the entry.
- `$2`: a " "(space)-separated list of `incond`.
- `$3`: a " "(space)-separated list of `outcond`.

For the "link" `A-B` to be valid, `jname` A must define B as `outcond`, and job B must define A as `incond`.

In the above example, `D-E` is not a valid "link" because E doesn't define D as `incond`.
`C-F` is not a valid "link" because F doesn't exist.

A `cond` is not valid if the link it forms is not valid. The script must detect all non valid `conds` and which jobs are infected.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    FS=" *; *";
    delim = "-";
    conds[""]=0;
}

{

    icnd_size = split($2, incond_list, " ");

    for (i=1; i<=icnd_size; ++i) {
    conds[incond_list[i] delim $1]++;
    }

    ocnd_size = split($3, outcond_list, " ");

    for (i=1; i<=ocnd_size; ++i) {
    conds[$1 delim outcond_list[i]]--;
    }

}

END {

    for (i in conds) {
    sz = split(i, answer, delim);

    if (conds[i] == 1) {
        j = answer[2];
        c = answer[1];
        inorout = "INCOND";
    }

    if (conds[i] == -1) {
        j = answer[1];
        c = answer[2];
        inorout = "OUTCOND";
    }

    if (conds[i] != 0)
        print "Invalid", inorout, c, "on job", j;
    }
}
```

The script works, although I do not have large data to test against. I see 2 problems with it:

1. the script will break if some `cond` has the character `delim` in the name
2. the script might break (and/or return false positives) if a line is inserted twice or if two lines have the same `jname`.

I could use any tip on addressing the two problems, as well as any critique of the code, it's literally my first Awk code.

Comment: Not really a CSV file is it! C => Comma => ','. You have a SSC. Semicolon separated file.

Comment: way late on this one, if you're still interestest, are you trying to make a `tsort` substitute here? Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

#### Your main questions

> The script works, although I do not have large data to test against.

You don't necessarily need a large dataset.
It's better to think of all possible corner cases.
For example, your sample data demonstrates failures of `OUTCOND` but not of `INCOND`.
Also, although there is an example of more than one outgoing links,
but there is no example of more than one incoming links.
There are not too many interesting cases,
if you add examples for all them,
then you can be fairly confident in your solution.

> 1. The script will break if some cond has the character delim in the name

If you want to be really safe, you could add a sanity check for that, and raise an error when such name is found, for example by calling `exit` with a non-zero value.

> 2. The script might break (and/or return false positives) if a line is inserted twice or if two lines have the same jname.

Ditto.

#### Simplify

Many things can be simplified in this code.

The `conds[""]=0;` is unnecessary, you can simply delete that line.

Instead of this:

> ```
> icnd_size = split($2, incond_list, " ");
>
> for (i=1; i<=icnd_size; ++i) {
> conds[incond_list[i] delim $1]++;
> }
> ```

You don't really need the return value of `split`,
because instead of a counting loop,
you can use a more idiomatic for-each loop:

```
split($2, inconds, " ");

for (i in inconds) {
    conds[inconds[i] delim $1]++;
}
```

The same goes for `outconds` as well.

#### Mutually exclusive `if` statements

These `if` statements cannot be both true at the same time:

> ```
> if (conds[i] == 1) {
>     # ...
> }
>
> if (conds[i] == -1) {
>     # ...
> }
> ```

So they should be chained together with an `else if`.

#### Formatting

Instead of this:

> ```
> for (i=1; i<=ocnd_size; ++i) {
> conds[$1 delim outcond_list[i]]--;
> }
> ```

It would be better to write like this:

```
for (i = 1; i <= ocnd_size; ++i) {
    conds[$1 delim outcond_list[i]]--;
}
```

#### Naming

Some of the names are not so great.
For example `sz`, `i`, `j`, `c` in the `END` block.
`sz` is actually unnecessary,
and I would rename the others to `pair`, `job`, and `cond`,
respectively.

#### Putting it together

Consider this alternative implementation:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    FS = " *; *";
    delim = "-";
}

{
    split($2, inconds, " ");

    for (i in inconds) {
        conds[inconds[i] delim $1]++;
    }

    split($3, outconds, " ");

    for (i in outconds) {
        conds[$1 delim outconds[i]]--;
    }
}

END {
    oformat = "Invalid %s %s on job %s\n";
    for (pair in conds) {
        split(pair, parts, delim);

        if (conds[pair] == 1) {
            job = parts[2];
            cond = parts[1];
            inorout = "INCOND";
        } else if (conds[pair] == -1) {
            job = parts[1];
            cond = parts[2];
            inorout = "OUTCOND";
        }
        if (conds[pair] != 0) print "Invalid", inorout, cond, "on job", job;
    }
}
```